# Custom Sorting in PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

My  Table:

```
    6   2/3/2013 row1
10      2/2/2013 row2
    1   1/3/2013 row3
2       1/3/2013 row4
```

If column1 has value (column2 will be empty)  Sort rows with column3.
Sort only those rows having value in column1 not the rows having value in column2.

If column2 has value (column1 will be empty) sort as per column2 . 
Sort only those rows having value in column2 not the rows having value in column1.

Sorting:

First iteration:

```
First column  column1 row1 is empty  and column2 has value so comparing row1 and row3, 1 is minimum so is in top.

    1   1/2/2013 row1
10      2/2/2013 row2
    6   2/3/2013 row3
2       1/3/2013 row4
```

Second iteration:

```
First column column1  row2 is there  so it comparing row2 and row4 for column3 date 1/3/2013 < 2/2/2013 so swap .

    1   1/2/2013 row1
2       1/3/2013 row2
    6   2/3/2013 row3
10      2/2/2013 row4
```

Third iteration:

```
First column column1  row3 is  empty in first column so and  comparing column2  since 1 < 6 so no changes.

    1   1/2/2013 row1
2       1/3/2013 row2
    6   2/3/2013 row3
10      2/2/2013 row4
```

Fourth iteration:

```
First column column1  row4 is there  so it comparing row2 and row4 for column3 date 1/3/2013 < 2/2/2013 so nothing.

    1   1/2/2013 row1
2       1/3/2013 row2
    6   2/3/2013 row3
10      2/2/2013 row4


Final Result After Sorting:

    1   1/2/2013 row1
2       1/3/2013 row2
    6   2/3/2013 row3
10      2/2/2013 row4
```

Is there good way to do it in PHP/mysql?

I tried with php sort function unable to find solution.

Thank You.

Comment: and do you want to leave the rows which has column 2 as is?

Comment: Yes both in column2 and column1 rows

Comment: I don't think there is an efficient way (or a way at all) to obtain this sorting in SQL only. I would probably take the PHP route. But then there should be no difficulty, you have described your algorithm very clearly, what is the problem?

Comment: @Yak Thank you,  I had some calculation to be done while sorting data in mysql which get out of sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for an interesting problem.  The solution seems to be:

```
SELECT *,col1+col2 p FROM test ORDER BY p;
```

this works for the test data you have supplied in this fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c7e2/4

This answer will only be correct if, as you say, only one column has a value.

Comment: Interesting approach, but a) if `col1` or `col2` may be null, use `COALESCE(col1, col2)` instead, because `1 + NULL = NULL`; and b) it does not cover the sorting condition on the date field.